# How to get multiple, independent views in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS I need 4 independent views: each view should be independent and have its own routing system: Imagine a single html page containing 4 different AngularJS apps all running together.

I know I need 4 modules for this, as each module can have only one view.
My question is: What is the best way to do something similar? Create 4 different Apps/modules (and then how do I have them communicate)? Or do something like this:

```
  angular.module('BirthdayApp', []);
  angular.module('CollectionApp', []);
  angular.module('DashboardApp', []);
  angular.module('FootballApp', []);

  // Lastly, I define my "main" module and inject all other modules as dependencies
  angular.module('MainApp',
  [
    'BirthdayApp',
    'CollectionApp',
    'DashboardApp',
    'FootballApp'
  ]
  );
```

or?

Tks!

Comment: `How to let them communicate this way`.  How independent should the be, if they still communicate?

Comment: I still don't know now which data could them share... anyway I would know if any kind of "modules communication" is allowed.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
Each module can communicate with services or events.

Comment: ok thank you! But ui-router uses "states" that don't fit exactly my needs. I'd prefere to use a simpler way without using external libraries!

Comment: Use AngularUI's router instead of ngRouter - it's much better and it'll let your page have multiple views. Angular2 will likely have a better system for managing multiple apps in one page - in Angular atm it's a pain.

Comment: Ok.. I'll try it! After finding hard for alternative solutions I found out it's the only painless solution. Tks :)